# When I am writing data to a CSV file thorough java few columns show improper data?

Tags: java, csv

So I am actually writing data to a CSV file through java. Now one of the column has value "047669602100001" and when it is written to the csv file it is showing as "4.76696E+13". I am sure that it is because of the column width. When i double click on that row it shows me the original record.

Is there anyway that I could follow to avoid this behavior?

Comment: A CSV doesn't have column width. It's pure text. What is really written in the CSV file, when you open it with a text editor?

Comment: Check out the MS-Excel documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't java's behavior.

`047669602100001` is being written to the CSV file properly. The program you are using to view it will see this as a large number and put it into scientific notation for display purposes. If you open the CSV file with a text editor you'll see that the correct value is actually recorded.

Comment: thanks...I have tried it and seems to be fine...

Comment: @Avinash if this helps, please mark this answer with the checkmark to signify to future visitors that this answer helped.

Comment: @hexafraction coaxing the newbies into accepting an answer....classic. Stackoverflow needs a poke feature to remind the new guys to accept haha